# What is "Token" on lab.pentestit.ru?

Tags: penetration-test, token

I am new to the Information Security field. Recently I found a virtual lab called "Pentestit"(https://lab.pentestit.ru/).
But I have a problem. After connecting via VPN, I can access target host: 192.168.101.5. I can scan and etc. But I do not know what's meant with "Token".
On the left side of the site there are fields for VPN token, site token, ssh token and etc.
What are these tokens and how can I find these?

Comment: It's sometimes also called a "flag", some piece of info you have to steal from the system you're attacking to prove you've successfully compromised it.

Answer (score 1):

When you find the vulnerabilities and hack through the system, you will see various files that contain strings like: token_ssh:. This is what you will have to use there.

Tokens are for you to prove your progress to the lab owners and participate in the contest. It is already won by Beched though.